# Can we load test a Desktop Application with Client Server architecture using Jmeter or any other load testing tool

Tags: load, automated-tests, jmeter, performance-testing

The application expects a load of 1000 users, about the protocols it uses, I am not very sure that, but is it doable load testing a Desktop Application with this Client Server Architecture with Jmeter
where users are uploading reports and contents from a Desktop app and the same gets received at a server from where the uploaded things can be fetched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See :

- [Load testing client-server based windows application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152788/load-testing-client-server-based-windows-application)

To answer more precisely this question you must give more infos about your Client/Server protocol, wether it's text or binary, standard or custom one...

The choice will depend on that.

Regards

Philippe